# hadoop hive loading error

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

While loading files to hadoop via hive. I got following error:

```
Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NotReplicatedYetException: Not replicated yet:/tmp/hive-hadoop/hive_2012-11-22_19-31-25_550_6464715632657097841/-ext-10000/outlog_11_oct12.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:422)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CopyTask
```

And according to other threads, its datanode issue, but all of my datanodes are up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem maybe lack of write permissions on `/tmp` directory.

Try `hadoop dfs -chmod g+w /tmp` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but group permissions are already there.